# Vectors pointing in same direction after transformation, despite change of dimensionality.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'v read this: [Do non-square matrices have eigenvalues?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583938/do-non-square-matrices-have-eigenvalues)

Where @Any explains that "*If $A$ is non-square, then $A:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, where $m\neq n$. Hence $Av=\lambda v$ makes no sense, since $Av\notin\mathbb{R}^m$*".

I understand that a non-square matrix can't satisfy the mathematical definition for eigenvectors/eigenvalues.

However, I always thought the motivation behind eigenvectors was to find the vectors that keep pointing in the same direction after a linear transformation, regardless of scaling.

In that sense, the vectors $<4, 5, 0>$ and $<4, 5>$ seem to follow that idea, despite the difference in dimensionality. After all, they point in exactly the same direction.

I know that a lot of mathematical concepts are defined out of convenience, as tools. I'm assuming Eigenvectors were defined because there is a lot of value in being able to identify vectors that keep pointing in the same direction after a transformation.

- Does that mean there is no value in identifying the vectors that remain pointing in the same direction if there is a change of dimensionality?
- If there is no such value, why not?
- And If there is value, what is that value and what tools have been developed to label and identify such vectors.